# Custom CollectionViewCell has default values when selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I try to use a collectionView inside a TableViewCell. I use the delegates, set it and so on - works fine:

```
class DetailTableViewController: UITableViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell:VideoCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("videoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! VideoCollectionViewCell
    // Doing some stuff here
    print(cell.videoNameLabel.text!) // Prints the right result
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("\(indexPath.row) tapped")
        let cell:VideoCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("videoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! VideoCollectionViewCell

        print(cell.videoNameLabel.text!) // Prints default value "Label"
    }
```

Here is the cell I use:

```
import UIKit

class VideoCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var videoNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

}
```

I have the functions mentioned above - when I open the TableViewController, it displays the right videoNameLabel Text for every Cell. I set the identifier "videoCell" in the storyboard and set the class for the cell.

But when I tap on the cell, it displays

> 0 tapped
>
> Label

Do you have any ideas how to fix this? I want to work with the cell, but it has the default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! VideoCollectionViewCell

        let text = cell.videoNameLabel.text!
        print(text)
}
```